# Apply property pandas.DataFrame.shape to multiple dataframe stored in a tuple

Tags: python, pandas

I have a function which returns as output a tuple containing multiple `pd.DataFrame` objects.

Take the example:

```
import pandas as pd

def myfunction():
    x = pd.DataFrame(data = [1,2,3])
    y = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
    return x, y

myfunction()
```

I am looking for a concise way to apply the property `pandas.DataFrame.shape` to each of the object stored in the tuple resulting from the call `myfunction()`.

#### The solution must not include a cycle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `operator.attrgetter`:

```
from operator import attrgetter

shapes = list(map(attrgetter('shape'), myfunction()))

[(3, 1), (2, 3)]
```

Although you are not looking for an explicit loop, this is the more readable version:

```
shapes = [x.shape for x in myfunction()]
```

Comment: Very complete and interesting. Thank you!